# Replace shape in center of Android Camera App

Tags: java, android, camera

I am currently designing an app that calls the Camera with a simple button click. I want to now change the shape that appears in the center of the camera (e.g. it is now a circle/rectangle depending on the device) to a custom shape. I am making a custom camera using a main activity class and a camera preview class. This is my code so far:

## Layout File

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/layout">

    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:contentDescription="@string/camstring"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/preview"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
    </FrameLayout>

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/buttonClick"
        android:contentDescription="@string/action"
        android:layout_gravity="center"></Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

## MainActivity

```
package com.test.Nurse_Cam;


import android.os.Bundle;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
import android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "CameraDemo";
    Camera camera;
    Preview preview;
    Button buttonClick;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        preview = new Preview(this);
        ((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.preview)).addView(preview);

        buttonClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonClick);
        buttonClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                preview.camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback,
                        jpegCallback);
            }
        });

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate'd");
    }

    ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {
        public void onShutter() {
            Log.d(TAG, "onShutter'd");
        }
    };

    /** Handles data for raw picture */
    PictureCallback rawCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - raw");
        }
    };

    /** Handles data for jpeg picture */
    PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            FileOutputStream outStream = null;
            try {
                // write to local sandbox file system
                // outStream =
                // CameraDemo.this.openFileOutput(String.format("%d.jpg",
                // System.currentTimeMillis()), 0);
                // Or write to sdcard
                outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format(
                        getString(R.string._sdcard_d_jpg), System.currentTimeMillis()));
                outStream.write(data);
                outStream.close();
                Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - jpeg");
        }
    };

}
```

## Preview Class

```
package com.test.Nurse_Cam;


import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
//import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback;
import android.hardware.Camera.Size;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;


@SuppressLint("SdCardPath")
class Preview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private static final String TAG = "Preview";
    //private final static double epsilon = 0.17;
    private Size mPreviewSize;


    SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    public Camera camera;
    public List<Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes = camera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Preview(Context context) {
        super(context);

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);

        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell it where
        // to draw.
        camera = Camera.open();

        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);

            camera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {

                public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera arg1) {
                    FileOutputStream outStream = null;
                    try {
                        outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format(
                                "/sdcard/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));
                        outStream.write(data);
                        outStream.close();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: "
                                + data.length);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                    }
                    Preview.this.invalidate();
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // Stopping preview because surface will be destroyed upon return

        camera.stopPreview();
        camera = null;
    }

    private Camera.Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Camera.Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
        final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
        double targetRatio=(double)h / w;

        if (sizes == null) return null;

        Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
        double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

        int targetHeight = h;

        for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
            double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
            if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE) continue;
            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }

        if (optimalSize == null) {
            minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
                if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }
            }
        }
        return optimalSize;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        final int width = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
        final int height = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);



        if (mSupportedPreviewSizes != null) {
          mPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes, width, height);
        }
    }


    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // Now that the size is known, set up the camera parameters and begin
        // the preview.

        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
        camera.setParameters(parameters);
        camera.startPreview();
    }
//      This adds a canvas to the app
    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.draw(canvas);
        Paint p = new Paint(Color.RED);
        Log.d(TAG, "draw");
        canvas.drawText("PREVIEW", canvas.getWidth() / 2,
                canvas.getHeight() / 2, p);
    }
}
```

The camera preview appears distorted when I use the app on my Galaxy S5 and I am unable to see the shape that usually appears in the center. Any input on the best way to place a custom shape in the center, replacing the usual one, would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use relative layout as parent layout of your XML and keep button into center by using `centerInParent=true` property hope it will not distorted on any device from now